# Select XML element without using Extension method

Tags: c#, xml, linq

The [MSDN - System.Xml.XPath Extensions Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says:

> There is some performance penalty for using these methods. Using LINQ to XML queries yields better performance.

And [XPathSelectElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083.aspx) is an extension method

I have following XML. I need to find out the messages and concatenate it. The challenge is - I need to select only messages that comes under `Status/StatusMsg/StatusDetail`. With `Descendants`, I am getting all the messages - even outside the required elements.

This can be achieved correctly using `XPathSelectElement`. But since XPathSelectElement is an extension method, it has some performance hit as shown in [LINQ to XML with XPath performance review](http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2008/12/04/LINQ-to-XML-and-LINQ-to-XML-with-XPath-performance-review.aspx) which says:

> In most cases running an XPath query will result in a 5 times longer execution period than querying using standard LINQ to XML.

What is the best way to do it without using extension method in LINQ to XML using C#?

Note: Is there a way to tweak `Descendants` for this purpose?

**XML**

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"  
          <Status>
                <StatusMsg>
                    <StatusType>INVOICE</StatusType>

                    <StatusDetail>
                        <Sequence test=""K"">  2  </Sequence>
                        <Message>A</Message>
                    </StatusDetail>

                    <StatusDetail>
                        <Message>B</Message>
                    </StatusDetail>

                    <StatusDetail>
                        <Message>C</Message>
                    </StatusDetail>
                </StatusMsg>

                    <StatusDetail>
                        <Message>OUTSIDE</Message>
                    </StatusDetail>
            </Status>
           ");
```

**CODE**

```
// Descendants
var messageArrayWithOutside = xDoc.Descendants(@"StatusDetail")
                             .Select(
                                       x => x.Element("Message") == null ? String.Empty : x.Element("Message").Value.Trim()
                                    ).ToArray();

var textAll = string.Join(", ", messageArrayWithOutside);

//XPathSelectElements
var messageArray = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(@"Status/StatusMsg/StatusDetail")
                           .Select(
                                     x => x.Element("Message") == null ? String.Empty : x.Element("Message").Value.Trim()
                                  ).ToArray();

var text = string.Join(", ", messageArray);
```

**UPDATE**

XPath seems to be faster than using Descendants two times. Any idea why?

```
        // Descendants
        Stopwatch stopWatchDescendants = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatchDescendants.Start();
        var messageArrayDecendants = xDoc.Descendants("StatusMsg")
            .Descendants("StatusDetail")
            .Select(
                x => x.Element("Message") == null ?string.Empty : x.Element("Message").Value.Trim()
            ).ToArray();

        var textDecendants = string.Join(", ", messageArrayDecendants);
        stopWatchDescendants.Stop();
        TimeSpan tsDescendants = stopWatchDescendants.Elapsed;


        //XPathSelectElements
        Stopwatch stopWatchXPath = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatchXPath.Start();
        var messageArrayXPath = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(@"Status/StatusMsg/StatusDetail")
                           .Select(
                                     x => x.Element("Message") == null ? String.Empty : x.Element("Message").Value.Trim()
                                  ).ToArray();

        var textXPath = string.Join(", ", messageArrayXPath);
        stopWatchXPath.Stop();
        TimeSpan tsXPath = stopWatchXPath.Elapsed;


        if (tsXPath > tsDescendants)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LINQ is fast");
        }
        if (tsDescendants > tsXPath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("XPath is fast");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("XPath :" + tsXPath.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("LINQ :" + tsDescendants.ToString());
```

Comment: Tangent, but your question has little to do with extension methods and much to do with xpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [.Elements(XName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) rather than [.Descendants(XName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) like the following:

```
var messageArrayWithOutside = xDoc.Elements("StatusMsg")
    .Elements("StatusDetail")
    .Select(
        x => 
            x.Element("Message") == null ? 
            string.Empty : 
            x.Element("Message").Value.Trim()
    ).ToArray();

var textAll = string.Join(", ", messageArrayWithOutside);
```

The textAll string will then contain the desired output and omit `OUTSIDE`:

```
A, B, C
```

The key seems to be using [.Elements(XName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) which limits the search that xDocument has to do the element's immediate children.

Comment: It doesn't compile - an error message comes - 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhitespace'. Any idea? Note: The project is in .Net4.0

Comment: XPath seems to be faster than using Descendants two times. Any idea why? I have updated the question